# Find percentages of total in a pivot query

Tags: sql, pivot

I have the following query that sums sales figures (linetotal) for each hour and day of the week:

```
Select * From(
Select datepart(DW,transdatetime) as [DOW], datepart(hour, transdatetime) as [Hour],linetotal
From   check_details
Where transdatetime between @BusinessDate1 and @BusinessDate2
) AS OrigTable
PIVOT
(
SUM(linetotal) 
FOR [DOW]
IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
) AS PivotTable
```

Instead of sums of actual sales figures, is it possible to provide the percent of sales for the entire day for each hour and day of the week?  The day's total will have to be calculated as a sum of linetotal.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest conditional aggregation:

```
Select datepart(hour, transdatetime) as [Hour],
datepart(DW,transdatetime) as [DOW], 
      linetotal,
      avg(case when datepart(weekday, transdatetime) = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as dow_1,
      avg(case when datepart(weekday, transdatetime) = 2 then 1.0 else 0 end) as dow_2,
      avg(case when datepart(weekday, transdatetime) = 3 then 1.0 else 0 end) as dow_3,
      avg(case when datepart(weekday, transdatetime) = 4 then 1.0 else 0 end) as dow_4,
      avg(case when datepart(weekday, transdatetime) = 5 then 1.0 else 0 end) as dow_5,
      avg(case when datepart(weekday, transdatetime) = 6 then 1.0 else 0 end) as dow_6,
      avg(case when datepart(weekday, transdatetime) = 7 then 1.0 else 0 end) as dow_7
From  check_details
Where transdatetime between @BusinessDate1 and @BusinessDate2
group by datepart(hour, transdatetime), lineitem
order by lineitem, datepart(hour, transdatetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I didn't need to do create this query.  It was for an SSRS report.  I created a separate query with totals, then did a calculation for each cell (1 each for 7 days) in the matrix tied to the above query.  Thank you for your attempt Gordon.